# Why does using PHP/cURL to log into a remote website throw a 400 error?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to write a PHP script using cURL that will eventually run a bunch of test on a website to check for content, however I can't seem to get past the actual logging in part.

This is the code that I'm currently trying:

```
function loginCurl() {
    $url = "https://mywebsite.com/main/login";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $login_page = curl_exec($ch);

    $csrf = preg_replace("/_csrf\"\svalue=\"/", "", substr($login_page, strpos($login_page, "_csrf"), 70));
    $username = "myEmail@mywebsite.com";
    $password = "abcde12345";

    $post_data = http_build_query(array( 
        '_csrf' => $csrf,
        'LoginForm' => array (
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'rememberMe' => 1
        )
    ));

    $HttpRequestHeaders = array(
        "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8",
        "Cache-Control:max-age=0",
        "Connection:keep-alive",
        "Referer:https://mywebsite.com/main/login",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1"
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,           "https://mywebsite.com/main/login");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,      true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,      '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,     'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,    'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,    $HttpRequestHeaders);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,        true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");
    $home_page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $home_page;
}
```

However, every time that I run this code, I end up with the server responding with an HTTP 400 error, although my request isn't malformed as far as I can see.

When I log into the actual website with the developer view open in Chrome, I can open up the login page under network and see all the data getting passed in the form fields, and it's just the 5 things I've got in my code. I'm not entirely sure why it's sending the "rememberMe" checkbox twice, but no matter how many times I send that box, it fails anyways.

The issue here is that now, although I have identical form data and request headers as when I log in to the real site manually, I still get a 400 error.

I guess my real question then comes in a few different parts:

1. Is there a better way to be logging into the website remotely than using cURL. As far as I'm aware, this is the best way.
2. If this is the best way to be doing it, is there a better way to tell exactly what's getting sent when I log in to the page than looking at the developer view's Form Data that it logs.
3. If there is not better way than what I'm doing, is it possible that the site is inaccurately throwing a 400 error, and it should really be something else? If that is the case, how would I get past this bug?

Finally, because I don't know if it's relevant, here's the actual stuff getting logged in the developer view:

```
Request headers: 

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/ *;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:212
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:_csrf=1c43726b4d2c2298b2667f1c9b47d420ee594f2de08a9ce928ee155b174c624aa%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22_csrf%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22niY-LESiKNwZkfg7mclgTuBPDJeLACz2%22%3B%7D; PHPSESSID=itnbbfiph1gj2p9movpmi9pmb7
Host:mywebsite.com
Origin:https://mywebsite.com
Referer:https://mywebsite.com/main/login
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36

Form Data:

_csrf:Z0owR2dpVXQJI2lqKywGHSwERx0MDzJDCilcIDMcFyQjAFULJiovRg==
LoginForm[username]:myEmail@mywebsite.com
LoginForm[password]:abcdefg12345
LoginForm[rememberMe]:0
LoginForm[rememberMe]:1
```

This is the developer view only stuff that it only tracks if you have it open.

And this is the stuff it logs for the actual request to the web page:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/ *;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:_csrf=1c43726b4d2c2298b2667f1c9b47d420ee594f2de08a9ce928ee155b174c624aa%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22_csrf%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22niY-LESiKNwZkfg7mclgTuBPDJeLACz2%22%3B%7D; PHPSESSID=i4ppm1ggcq1cq6hkvilesggr10; _identity=2ca675db2d582db9f7ab8761cc0a07a14e2e2dece90386b11392b270637b0559a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A9%3A%22_identity%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A19%3A%22%5B1267%2Cnull%2C2592000%5D%22%3B%7D
Host:mywebsite.com
Referer:https://mywebsite.com/main/login
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
```

This is the tag in the sites HTML that contains the csrf token, when I echo the csrf, it displays as should. I don't believe there's a parsing error, however it does appear differently in the HTTP response headers, which is strange to me.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="T25ZVmZGZi4hBwB7KgM1RwQgLgwNIAEZIg01MTIzJH4LJDwaJwUcHA==">
```

I hope someone is able to help me out with this, I've been going at it for a few days now!

Comment: You do a few mistakes, you don't properly urlencode the LoginForm array (that's probably why you can't login), you don't handle encoded responses, even though you tell the server that you accept ‘gzip, deflate, sdch, br‘ , and you manually set the host header.. but I'm not gonna correct you from a phone

Comment: @hanshenrik - Thank you for your quick reply! The LoginForm isn't actually an array, it's just the value of the name field. It's a little weird, but their name field is name="LoginForm[username]", it's not just username. So do you mean the actual [ ] braces should be urlencoded to %5B %5D instead or [ ]? Also, I'm not sure what gzip, deflate, sdch and br actually are, those are just the request header that come from actually logging. How do I handle those?

Comment: yes, repalce [ with %5B and ] with %5D, and you'll probably be able to log in. but that' still terrible way to encode the data, you should be using http_build_query ^^

Comment: PS, looking at the test data you provide, looks like your preg code isn't able to properly extract the CSRF token. your curl csrf `Z0owR2dpVXQJI2lqKywGHSwERx0MDzJDCilcIDMcFyQjAFULJiovRg==`  looks *nothing* like the recorded csrf `1c43726b4d2c2298b2667f1c9b47d420ee594f2de08a9ce928ee155b174c624aa%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22_csrf%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22niY-LESiKNwZkfg7mclgTuBPDJeLACz2%22%3B%7D`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do a couple of mistakes,

your post_data is not properly encoded, `[` should be `%5B` , and the `]` should be `%5D`, like
`"&LoginForm%5Busername%5D=" . urlencode($username)`
, furthermore, you're redefining LoginForm[rememberMe] to both `0` and `1` in the same form, pretty sure that's not legal.

but rather than making the encoded string yourself, which is ugly and (as you have just proven) error-prone, have `http_build_query` do it for you, like this:

```
$post_data = http_build_query ( array (
        '_csrf' => $csrf,
        'LoginForm' => array (
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password,
                'rememberMe' => 1 
        ) 
) );
```

and you say that you `"Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br"` , but you provide no code to handle any of those encodings, should the server decide to use any of them, and your loginCurl() function has no way of telling the caller which encoding the server decided to use.. best way of handling that, is to have curl handle encodings for you, automatically. don't send the `accept-encoding` header yourself, but set `CURLOPT_ENCODING` to emptstring `''`, and curl will automatically `accept-encoding: <all encodings that libcurl was compiled with here>` - and automatically decode it, if the server decided to use an encoding.

and you set the `"Host:` header manually, don't do that, let curl set it for you, as `curl_init`does for you (or use `CURLOPT_URL`), furthermore, you probably want to use `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` rather than setting the useragent header yourself (its easy to forget if you do it manually)

also, some pages can detect that you're faking the `referrer` header, you should probably just set CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, and make a GET request to the url you want a referrer from first, rather than faking the referrer header :P

question `Is there a better way to be logging into the website remotely than using cURL. As far as I'm aware, this is the best way.` - if there's not a specific api for the website, then, in my experience, (lib)curl is the best way to log in like a browser.

question `If this is the best way to be doing it, is there a better way to tell exactly what's getting sent when I log in to the page than looking at the developer view's Form Data that it logs.`  - idk, but 99% of the time, chrome developer tools works fine for me. sometimes, i have to resort to `Fiddler Proxy` or `ReDox Packet Editor`, when i want analyze non-browser applications, though..

question `If there is not better way than what I'm doing, is it possible that the site is inaccurately throwing a 400 error, and it should really be something else? If that is the case, how would I get past this bug?`
  - well, as i've said higher up, you're doing it wrong here, but when it `works in the browser, and doesn't work in curl`, the trick is compare the request that curl does, with the request that chrome does, and systematically take away every single difference between the curl-based request and browser-based request, until they're exactly equal, and retrying every step of the way.. FiddlerProxy and netcat (common in Linux, needs Cygwin in windows) comes in handy here

edit 9001:

PS, looking at the test data you provide, looks like your preg `$csrf = preg_replace(...` code isn't able to properly extract the CSRF token. your curl csrf `Z0owR2dpVXQJI2lqKywGHSwERx0MDzJDCilcIDMcFyQjAFULJiovRg==`  looks *nothing* like the recorded csrf `1c43726b4d2c2298b2667f1c9b47d420ee594f2de08a9ce928ee155b174c624aa%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22_csrf%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22niY-LESiKNwZkfg7mclgTuBPDJeLACz2%22%3B%7D`

Comment: Thank you so much for your very in depth response! I've followed your suggested changes, but I'm still getting 400 errors. I've modified the question to include my updated code. Also, as for the rememberMe getting set twice, I don't really understand that either, but when checking the developer tools, it shows it twice as I've shown above.

Comment: @nixin72 i bet the problem is that you don't extract (or calculate?) the csrf token properly... what website is it?

Comment: @nixin72 protip, when debugging why your curl code isn't working, don't settle for `CURLOPT_HEADER`, use `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` & `CURLOPT_STDERR`. like `$curldebugh=tmpfile();$curldebuguri=stream_get_contents($curldebugh)['uri'];curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>true,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$curldebuguri));...curl_exec($ch);$debuginfo=file_get_contents($curldebuguri); var_dump($debuginfo); `  - which is pretty much what i'm doing with my curl wrapper lib `hhb_curl`'s ->getStdErr() in https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php

Comment: Not too sure what that code is doing. Creates a temporary file, then gets the contents of it, which would be nothing, set the CURL options, I get that, but then what's the `...curl_exec($ch)`? Then it reads the contents again and dumps them to browser. I'm familiar with `...` in the sense of using it as a parameter in a function to throw all the past variables passed in to an array, but not sure what it's doing here.

Comment: @nixin72 does this code work? if you just switch out the username/password on line 24? https://pastebin.com/anXsPsUK - with hhb_.inc.php from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php

Comment: Give me a bit to find out, I need to convert your script from GitHub to PHP5.5. Unless you have it in 5.5 already. I'm unfortunately not running PHP7 yet.....

Comment: *i think* just removing all the input & return type declarations should be sufficient

Comment: Look like it so far, I haven't seen any of the PHP7 operators, so I'm just dropping any reference to a datatype.

Comment: you don't need anything except hhb_curl, so just rip out that one. (the others like hhb_bcmath, use some php7 features, and you don't need em.  hhb_var_dump is php5 compatible already (back in the day, it was even PHP4 compatible), but you don't need that either)

Comment: Almost done converting, just need to handle this: $domd = @ DOMDocument::loadHTML( $hc->getResponseBody()); Not entirely sure how would this translates to PHP5.x, could you help me out with that line? It's pulled from your snippet on pastebin. I have all of your script converted now.

Comment: @nixin72 that line is PHP5-compatible. but you need the php-xml extension installed (`apt install php5-xml` in ubunt/debian, or ./configure with `--enable-libxml` if you're compiling php from source..)

Comment: maybe try `preg_match('/name\=\"_csrf\"\s+value\=\"([^\"]*)/',$hc->getResponseBody(),$matches); $csrf=$matches[1];`  instead. it's way less fool-proof than a proper XML parser, but... i don't trust your csrf extraction code, try this instead. your code might confuse the cookie csrf token with the HTML csrf token, which on this website is different. this regex extraction should not do that mistake. (you were using CURLOPT_HEADER, meaning that cookies and html was mixed)

Comment: I made a pull request to your git repo with the new file. Thank you so much once again, this would've taken me forever to figure out!